# How to get iteration count in cucumber?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I wanted to get iteration count in cucumber when we are executing feature file with multiple row from example in feature file.
**->** Imagine a situation wherein we have two rows of First Scenario outline, say A1 and A2, and two of the Second one, say B1 and B2, to be executed Parallel
**SCENARIO 1**
Examples:
| num1 | num2 | total |
| -2   | 3    | 1     |--**A1**
| 10   | 15   | 25    |--**A2**
**SCENARIO 2**
Examples:
| num1 | num2 | total |
| 4   | 5    | 9     |--**B1**
| 13   | 12   | 25    |--**B2**
**EXPECTED STATUS OF ABOVE TWO SCENARIOS EXECUTED IN PARALLEL**
Thread  ScenarioOutline InvocationCount Status
1   A1  1   **OK**
2   B1  1   **OK**
3   A2  1   **NOT OK**
Please help us how this can be handled, as this may be the case in parallel execution.

Comment: Does iteration count means that it is a counter of the total number of scenarios run and NOT count of rows in individual scenario outlines? If so go back to my original answer and make the count++ inside a synchronized block. Check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy of "CucumberScenarioOutline.java" under main/java/cucumber/runtime/model.

Then you can modify the below method after declaring a global variable say intCurrentRow -

```
@override
public void run(Formatter formatter, Reporter reporter, Runtimeruntime) {
    formatOutlineScenario(formatter);
    for (CucumberExamples cucumberExamples : cucumberExamplesList) {
        cucumberExamples.format(formatter);
        List<CucumberScenario> exampleScenario = cucumberExamples.createExampleScenarios();
        intCurrentRow = 1;  //Hereyou can ititiate your variable
        for (CucumberScenario exampleScenario : exampleScenarios) {
            exampleScenario.run(formatter, reporter, runtime);
            intCurrentRow++;  //Here you can increase iteration number
        }
    }
}
```

You can also copy the code below to create the CucumberScenarioOutline.java

```
package cucumber.runtime.model;

import cucumber.runtime.CucumberException;
import cucumber.runtime.Runtime;
import gherkin.formatter.Formatter;
import gherkin.formatter.Reporter;
import gherkin.formatter.model.DataTableRow;
import gherkin.formatter.model.DocString;
import gherkin.formatter.model.Examples;
import gherkin.formatter.model.ExamplesTableRow;
import gherkin.formatter.model.Row;
import gherkin.formatter.model.Scenario;
import gherkin.formatter.model.ScenarioOutline;
import gherkin.formatter.model.Step;
import gherkin.formatter.model.Tag;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class CucumberScenarioOutline extends CucumberTagStatement {
    private final List<CucumberExamples> cucumberExamplesList = new ArrayList<CucumberExamples>();
    private final CucumberBackground cucumberBackground;

    public CucumberScenarioOutline(CucumberFeature cucumberFeature, CucumberBackground cucumberBackground, ScenarioOutline scenarioOutline) {
        super(cucumberFeature, scenarioOutline);
        this.cucumberBackground = cucumberBackground;
    }

    public void examples(Examples examples) {
        cucumberExamplesList.add(new CucumberExamples(this, examples));
    }

    public List<CucumberExamples> getCucumberExamplesList() {
        return cucumberExamplesList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Formatter formatter, Reporter reporter, Runtime runtime) {
        format(formatter);
        for (CucumberExamples cucumberExamples : cucumberExamplesList) {
            cucumberExamples.format(formatter);
            List<CucumberScenario> exampleScenarios = cucumberExamples.createExampleScenarios();
            for (CucumberScenario exampleScenario : exampleScenarios) {
                exampleScenario.run(formatter, reporter, runtime);
            }
        }
    }

    CucumberScenario createExampleScenario(ExamplesTableRow header, ExamplesTableRow example, List<Tag> examplesTags) {
        // Make sure we replace the tokens in the name of the scenario
        String exampleScenarioName = replaceTokens(new HashSet<Integer>(), header.getCells(), example.getCells(), getGherkinModel().getName());

        Scenario exampleScenario = new Scenario(example.getComments(), examplesTags, getGherkinModel().getKeyword(), exampleScenarioName, "", example.getLine(), example.getId());
        CucumberScenario cucumberScenario = new CucumberScenario(cucumberFeature, cucumberBackground, exampleScenario, example);
        for (Step step : getSteps()) {
            cucumberScenario.step(createExampleStep(step, header, example));
        }
        return cucumberScenario;
    }

    static ExampleStep createExampleStep(Step step, ExamplesTableRow header, ExamplesTableRow example) {
        Set<Integer> matchedColumns = new HashSet<Integer>();
        List<String> headerCells = header.getCells();
        List<String> exampleCells = example.getCells();

        // Create a step with replaced tokens
        String name = replaceTokens(matchedColumns, headerCells, exampleCells, step.getName());

        return new ExampleStep(
                step.getComments(),
                step.getKeyword(),
                name,
                step.getLine(),
                rowsWithTokensReplaced(step.getRows(), headerCells, exampleCells, matchedColumns),
                docStringWithTokensReplaced(step.getDocString(), headerCells, exampleCells, matchedColumns),
                matchedColumns);
    }

    private static List<DataTableRow> rowsWithTokensReplaced(List<DataTableRow> rows, List<String> headerCells, List<String> exampleCells, Set<Integer> matchedColumns) {
        if (rows != null) {
            List<DataTableRow> newRows = new ArrayList<DataTableRow>(rows.size());
            for (Row row : rows) {
                List<String> newCells = new ArrayList<String>(row.getCells().size());
                for (String cell : row.getCells()) {
                    newCells.add(replaceTokens(matchedColumns, headerCells, exampleCells, cell));
                }
                newRows.add(new DataTableRow(row.getComments(), newCells, row.getLine()));
            }
            return newRows;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static DocString docStringWithTokensReplaced(DocString docString, List<String> headerCells, List<String> exampleCells, Set<Integer> matchedColumns) {
        if (docString != null) {
            String docStringValue = replaceTokens(matchedColumns, headerCells, exampleCells, docString.getValue());
            return new DocString(docString.getContentType(), docStringValue, docString.getLine());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String replaceTokens(Set<Integer> matchedColumns, List<String> headerCells, List<String> exampleCells, String text) {
        for (int col = 0; col < headerCells.size(); col++) {
            String headerCell = headerCells.get(col);
            String value = exampleCells.get(col);
            String token = "<" + headerCell + ">";

            if (text.contains(token)) {
                text = text.replace(token, value);
                if (text.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new CucumberException("Step generated from scenario outline '" + token + "' is empty");
                }
                matchedColumns.add(col);
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way but not a very flexible way is to create a column with the iteration number.

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers <num1> & <num2>
    Given I have a calculator
    When I add <num1> and <num2> for iteration number <itrnum>
    Then the result should be <total>

  Examples: 
    | itrnum | num1 | num2 | total |
    | 1 | -2 | 3 | 1 |
    | 2 | 10 | 15 | 25 |
    | 3 | 99 | -99 | 0 |
```

Other is the use the before hook to get this information. For this give the `scenariooutline` a tag, lets say `@Counter`. Create a `Before hook` only for the `@Counter` tag. Use a static variable to keep the count. So this before hook will only run where the counter tag is present. Static is required as a fresh instance of the hook and step classes are created for each row of a scenario outline.

```
@Counter
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers <num1> & <num2>
        Given I have a calculator
        When I add <num1> and <num2>
        Then the result should be <total>

      Examples: 
        | num1 | num2 | total |
        | -2 | 3 | 1 |
        | 10 | 15 | 25 |
        | 99 | -99 | 0 |
```

---

```
private static int count = 0;

@Before("@Counter") 
public void countScenarioOutlineRows() {
    count++;
}
```

### ----------

**UPDATED** - for multiple scenario outlines.
You can use a static map to store the counters. But for this you will need to add some kind of key to the scenariooutline description.

```
@Counter
    Scenario Outline: SO1 ## Add two numbers <num1> & <num2>

@Counter
    Scenario Outline: SO2 ## Multiply two numbers <num1> & <num2>
```

---

```
private static Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();

    @Before("@Counter") 
    public void countScenarioOutlineRows(Scenario sce) {
        //Get descrition on scenrio outline
        System.out.println("SCENARIO NAME -- " +sce.getName());
        String key = sce.getName().substring(0, sce.getName().indexOf("##") - 1);
        System.out.println("SCENARIO KEY --" + key + "--");

        counter.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);
    }
```

If you do not want to store all details in a Map, then store the counter in a static integer. Switch it to 0 when the description changes else add 1 to it. For this you will also need to store the scenariooutline description in a temporary static variable for comparison.

Comment: #Grasshopper Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It is not working when you have more than one scenario in feature file.

Comment: And the issue is? You will need to setup multiple static variables and hooks for multiple scenariooutlines. One to one mapping

Comment: How will you handle if scenariooutline count is dynamic.  We dont know scenario count in feature file Bcoz under one folder we have multiple feature files which again have multiple scenariooutlines

Comment: @kiranB Updated, think it should work for your requierment

Comment: This holds good for a single thread execution, but it doesn't seem to handle when we have parallel execution happening.

Comment: Use a ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: Imagine a situation wherein we have two rows of First Scenario outline, say A1 and A2, and two of the Second one, say B1 and B2

Comment: take below example

Thread Scenario Outline Invocation Count Status
1             A1                  1                          OK
2             B1                  1                          OK
3             A2                  1                       NOT OK

Comment: I am unable to understand the issue. Can you edit the original question and add the details there as it will be much clearer. Thx

Comment: #Grasshopper I have updated questions description please have a look into it