# Incrementing variables in Cucumber features

Tags: java, variables, cucumber

I have a fairly standard Cucumber feature file along the lines of:

```
    Scenario Outline: Check invalid message queue
    When a request is sent
    Then there is 1 item in the invalid queue
```

I'm currently running these with an additional column of "count" in my Examples table so my feature looks like:

```
    Scenario Outline: Check invalid message queue
    When a request is sent
    Then there is < count > item in the invalid queue
```

And my examples are:

```
    | Var1   |  var2  |  count  |
    | aaa    |  aa1   |    1    |
    | bbb    |  aa2   |    2    |
```

etc

Although its not a major issue to do the above it falls over when a test fails, if we have say 10 tests in the Examples and test 5 does not go to the queue then logically all of the following tests fail as the queue will always have one less item in it.

What I'd ideally want is to have "count" start at 0 and then increment every time the test passes so I wouldn't have a "count" column and if test 5 fails then the count remains at 4 when it goes into test 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend to have dependencies between examples inside a scenario outline, they should normally be runnable separately in JUnit.

The recommended approach is to create scenarios with a predefined state (Given I have X messages in my  queue), or at worst one scenario which alternates actions ("When a request is sent") and outcome check ("Then there is X messages in my queue").
If you still want to proceed, I think what you're looking for is here :
[How to get iteration count in cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506122/how-to-get-iteration-count-in-cucumber)
The @Before hook by Grasshopper is a good solution.